# Recuperar IP Externo sem serviços de terceiros

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Tenho uma aplicação WPF. Eu preciso saber o IP externo da máquina que está rodando essa aplicação.

Eu achei alguns tutoriais que ensinam fazer isso através do método `DownloadString()` da classe `WebClient` consumindo alguns serviços como `dyndns.org`, `icanhazip.com`, enfim vários serviços.

Seria algo assim:

```
string meuIp = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
```

Para usar tais serviços eu preciso implementar a consulta em pelo menos uns dois ou três para garantir uma contingência em caso de algum serviço parar de funcionar ou for descontinuado.

Alguém sabe se é possível fazer isso nativamente com o .Net Framework sem utilizar serviços de terceiros?

Comment: Que tipo de aplicação você esta utilizando? poderia posta como esta tentando fazer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [...] é possível fazer isso nativamente com o .Net Framework sem utilizar serviços de terceiros?

Não, não é possível. Sua máquina tem acesso apenas ao IP local, fornecido pelo serviço interno de DNS ou setado manualmente.

O IP externo é, na grande maioria das vezes, o fornecido pelo seu provedor para que você seja acessível via NAT (Network address translation), como na imagem abaixo:

[image: NAT categorization according to RFC]

<sup>[NAT categorization according to RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Full_Cone_NAT.svg), Wikipedia</sup>

Neste caso você sempre irá precisar de um serviço externo que lhe diga, *do ponto de vista dele*, com qual IP você está se conectando.

Comment: Será que é isso mesmo? Toda vez que um pacote sai para a Internet a partir do meu roteador, ele sai carregando o meu IP externo (IP do meu roteador, atribuído pelo meu serviço de Internet), certo? Se eu não colocar essa informação no pacote, o host destino jamais saberia para onde retornar a resposta. Assim, um serviço que revela o meu IP externo, na verdade, apenas me retorna de volta uma informação que o meu próprio roteador enviou para ele. A informação do meu IP externo fica guardada no meu roteador. A questão que se coloca é: como recuperá-la sem enviar pacotes para fora da minha rede?

Comment: @Leonardo o modelo que você descreveu é correto caso você assuma que não existe nenhuma outra camada NAT entre o seu roteador e a internet, o que em muitas vezes não é verdade; seu roteador pode receber um IP de uma camada intermediária, como por exemplo via CGNAT (Carrier Grade Network Address Translation).

Comment: você está me falando então que o meu IP externo pode não ficar em posse do meu roteador? Eu realmente tenho dificuldade de compreender isso. Porque, mesmo nesse caso, quando eu faço uma requisição para fora, o ISP tem de saber de onde ela partiu e o IP que me identifica para o ISP pode não ser meu IP externo? É isso? Se for, no caso do CGNAT, o ISP me fornece um IP privado? E, sendo o CGNAT como um NAT ordinário, no domínio do ISP, pode acontecer de duas redes na Internet terem o mesmo IP público, não?

Comment: @Leonardo No caso do CGNAT mais comum, (NAT444 - Private to Private to Public NAT) ocorre uma translação de endereços de rede entre a rede interna e a intermediária (mediada pelo gateway do seu roteador) e outra entre a rede intermediária e a internet (mediada pelo ISP). Os endereços são únicos por camada. Referência: https://www.a10networks.com/blog/carrier-grade-nat/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [IP Public Knowledge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IpPublicKnowledge/).

instale o pacote NuGet:

> Install-Package IpPublicKnowledge

Um exemplo de utilização seria este:

```
var ip = IPK.GetMyPublicIp();
var IPinfo = IPK.GetIpInfo(ip);
    
Console.WriteLine("IP Publico: " + IPinfo.IP);
Console.WriteLine("ISP: " + IPinfo.isp);
Console.WriteLine("País: " + IPinfo.country);
```

Outra forma, como você mesmo disse, seria utilizar algum site externo, como por exemplo:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");            
    Console.WriteLine(externalip);
}
```

Para esse caso, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444495/4843158) mostra mais exemplos para garantir a contingência.

Caso queira outros exemplos, [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3253701/4843158) possui diversas formas de como fazer isso, inclusive uma de como criar o seu próprio Http Server para isso.

Comment: Essa biblioteca internamente não utiliza estes sites? Só pra ter certeza. Valeu pela resposta

Comment: @Murilo Utilizam sim. O código dela você pode ver [neste código](https://github.com/cl-dbiya/IPK/blob/master/IpPublicKnowledge/IPK.cs).

Comment: @Murilo A resposta do OnoSendai explica melhor o motivo de ter que utilizar algum serviço.