# Como resgatar endereço de IP externo no Android?

Tags: android, ip

O endereço **IPV4** local não é algo muito complexo de resgatar, dá para fazer isso usando a classe [`NetworkInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html). Porém além do local, existe também o [IP externo](http://www.meuip.com.br/), no qual percebi que algumas pessoas usam algumas **APIs**, como a do [WhatIsMyIP](https://www.whatismyip.com/api-documentation/#quick-start-guide), para retorno de informações referente a rede. No WhatIsMyIP existe a versão free, porém muito limitada.

Existe uma forma de resgatar IP externo sem necessidade de um serviço externo? Se sim, como poderia fazer isso? Se não, qual maneira viável de fazer isso?

Comment: Parece que [isto não é possivel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6932465/5524514), já que quem fica a frente da rede é o roteador/modem. Alias, nem um computador é capaz de determinar o ip externo por si só atrás de um NAT.

Comment: @diegofm eu não tinha visto essa resposta do SOen! Talvez há algum serviço de baixo custo que possivelmente resolverá esse problema. Vou fazer algumas pesquisas. =P

Comment: Relacionado [Recuperar IP Externo sem serviços de terceiros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166395/recuperar-ip-externo-sem-servi%c3%a7os-de-terceiros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como explicado nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166404/3635) **não é possivel** fazer isto sem depender de um serviço externo:

> Não, não é possível. Sua máquina tem acesso apenas ao IP local, fornecido pelo serviço interno de DNS ou setado manualmente.
>
> O IP externo é, na grande maioria das vezes, o fornecido pelo seu provedor para que você seja acessível via NAT (Network address translation), como na imagem abaixo:
>
> [image: NAT categorization according to RFC]
>
> <sup>[NAT categorization according to RFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Full_Cone_NAT.svg), Wikipedia</sup>
>
> Neste caso você sempre irá precisar de um serviço externo que lhe diga, *do ponto de vista dele*, com qual IP você está se conectando.

### Como obter o IP com serviços externos

Existem vários serviços de terceiros que disponibilizam isto, como por exemplo:

- http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.whatismyip.org/
- https://wtfismyip.com
- https://ipinfo.io/ip

No entanto todos eles tem pontos em comum, sendo um serviço de terceiros pode ocorrer de muitas pessoas ao redor do mundo usando uma hora o serviço parar, não estou dizendo para não usar, mas é sempre bom ter um fallback.

Eu diria que um bom caminho seria ter um servidor próprio, geralmente apps mobile usam internet, se o teu app vai disponibilizar acesso a algum dado online para o usuário o melhor seria fazer a checagem do IP neste momento no próprio servidor, um exemplo usando [*DefaultHttpClient*](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html):

```java
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://meuservidor/api/ip");

try
{
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    //Resposta, pode ser uma String
    EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Log.d("error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

No entanto se o aplicativo realmente não tem nenhum servidor por qualquer que seja o motivo, "não há mal algum" em usar serviços de terceiros, desde que haja pelo menos um fallback, por exemplo você tenta o serviço 1, se ele falha porque esta fora do ar, você tenta o serviço 2 e assim por diante.

Neste caso seria interessante também colocar um timeout bem curto para não parecer que o aplicativo é lento, por exemplo:

```java
//Configura
HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();

int timeoutConnection = 2000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameters, timeoutConnection);

int timeoutSocket = 2000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(parameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(parameters);

// Começa a requisição a partir daqui...
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlDoServico);
```

No geral o código ficaria assim:

```
String myIp;

String[] toppings = { "http://servico1.com", "http://servico2.com", "http://servico3.com" };

//Configura
HttpParams parameters = new BasicHttpParams();

int timeoutConnection = 2000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(parameters, timeoutConnection);

int timeoutSocket = 2000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(parameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(parameters);

// Começa a requisição a partir daqui...
HttpGet request;

final Pattern regexValidateIp = Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,3}\\.d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$");

for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    request = new HttpGet(services[i]);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        //Pode tratar a a resposta aqui
        String resposeData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        if (regexValidateIp.matcher(resposeData).find()) {
             myIp = resposeData;
             break; //Finaliza o loop
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

//Exibe o IP
Log.d("IP:", myIp);
```

Claro que é bom lembrar que alguns retorna JSON, outros retornam HTML, então talvez você possa pegar o header `Content-Type` e verificar isto, você pode colocar isto dentro de uma `Thread` ou algo assim, já que a checagem pode levar algum tempo.

Comment: Vlw Bro! Tmj...